# How to set migradoc chart x axis tickmarks

Tags: c#, charts, axis, migradoc

I assign manually values to the labels of the x-axis. Every 150 steps there should be a value. The rest is `String.Empty`. This part works perfectly.

```
Chart plotter = plotter_ref.Clone();

XSeries xseries = plotter.XValues.AddXSeries();
xseries.Add("0");
for (int i = 2; i <= 600; i++)
{
    if (i % 150 == 0)
    {
        xseries.Add(i.ToString());                    
    }
    else
    {
        xseries.Add(String.Empty);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to have Tickmarks at those points where the values are. I tried to set the `MajorTickMark` property

```
plotter.XAxis.MajorTick = 150;
plotter.XAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Cross;
// or this 
//plotter.XAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Inside;
```

But it has no effect:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

If I take a closer look at the [Tutorial](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx) in the sample chart section their [example](http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/GetFile.aspx?File=%2fHelloMigraDoc-sample%2fHelloMigraDoc_output.pdf) also does not show any x-axis ticks. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I encountered the same thing and now trying to find a solution.

Comment: @mcy unfortunately I have not. I played around a lot with it, but could not figure it out.

Comment: Yeah, me too. Just abandoned the ticks in the end.

Comment: @mcy I also abandoned the ticks. One work around that I used because of another problem is to plot it in an actual Winforms.Charts (which is a little more handy) then save it to a *.png or *.jpeg file and load the image into the table in the PDF. Did also the trick. Is just a little more fiddling ;)

Answer (score 0):

what if you did another trick? i.e. while printing the values there, you did like this:

```
xseries.Add( "+" + Environment.NewLine + i.ToString()) );
```

thus, it will insert like this:

```
--------------------------------------
           +          +
0         150        300
```

and just positioned 12pixel above?